# How to get only the current date and the previous dates in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am trying to get only the current dates and the previous dates.Here is how i tried

```
$jobseekers = Calllog::orderBy('calllogs.created_at','DESC')
              ->get()->where('call_back_date', '<=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

This show only the previous dates, i want to get both.If i remove "<", it shows only the current date.Help me out please.

Comment: `Carbon::today()` returns the today date at 00:00:00 (hours and minutes). Try `Carbon::now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$jobseekers = Calllog::orderBy('calllogs.created_at','DESC')->where('call_back_date', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
```

Using now() instead of today(). Unlike today(), now() returns complete datetime at the moment.

Also notice that i moved where condition before get() to prevent fetching extra data from database.

Comment: If using `now`, time of the next part of a day (after current moment) doesn't match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tomorrow` and `<` condition

```
$jobseekers = Calllog::orderBy('calllogs.created_at','DESC')
    ->get()->where('call_back_date', '<', Carbon::tomorrow()->toDateString());
```

Answer (score 1):

use below eloquent query

```
    $jobseekers = Calllog::whereDate('call_back_date','<=',Carbon::today)->get()
```